# How to session manually in a java project that connects to a JMS MQ with xml as payload and gets the response from the remote jms endpoint

Tags: jms

I have been searching for Java code to send an XML payload to the JMS endpiont and also receive the response in XML format only. Everyone is writing the producer and consumer but nobody is giving code for existing jms endpoint with payload.

Plug In- Tibco EMS

```
Connection factory – com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnectonfactory
Server URL - tcp://10.xxx.xx.xx:69999
User name – scott
Password - tiger
```

XML payload:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MYServices>
    <header>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </header>
    <body>
        <srv_req>
            <req_due_amount>
                <card_no>blablanumber</card_no>
            </req_due_amount>
        </srv_req>
    </body>
</MYServices>
```

JMS endpoint

```
jms://session_name::queue_name::request_topic
```

Comment: What is this "JMS endpoint" you're referring to? This is not part of the JMS specification. It looks like a custom URL for some 3rd party integration software. Please clarify.

Comment: Its tibco JMS queue and I need to send xml payload to that jms endpoint .please refer the manual process here https://www.soapui.org/jms/working-with-jms-messages/

Answer (score 0):

```
    import javax.jms.*;
    import java.util.Enumeration;

    public class JMSExample{

protected static final String SERVICE_QUEUE = "QUEUE_NAME_THAT_IS_CREDTED_IN_SERVER_FOR_ACCEPTING";
static String serverUrl = "tcp://10.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx";
static String userName = "UR_UserID";
static String password = "UR_Pass";

public static void sendTopicMessage(String topicName, String messageStr) {

    Connection connection = null;
    Session session = null;
    MessageProducer msgProducer = null;
    Destination destination = null;

    try {
        TextMessage msg;
        System.out.println("Publishing to destination '" + topicName
                + "'\n");
        ConnectionFactory factory = new com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnectionFactory(serverUrl);
        connection = factory.createConnection(userName, password);
        connection.start();
        session = connection
                .createSession(false,javax.jms.Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        TemporaryQueue tempQueue = session.createTemporaryQueue();

        TextMessage message_t = session.createTextMessage(messageStr);
        //This step is compulsory to get the reply from JMS server
        message_t.setJMSReplyTo(tempQueue);
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(session.createQueue(SERVICE_QUEUE));
        producer.send(message_t);

        System.out.println("INFO::  The producer has sent the message"+message_t);
        Destination dest = tempQueue;

        MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(dest);
        Message replyMsg = consumer.receive();
        TextMessage tm = (TextMessage) replyMsg;
        System.out.println("INFO The response is "+ replyMsg);
        consumer.close();
        producer.close();
        session.close();
        connection.close();

    } catch (JMSException e) {
         System.out.println("Error :: there was exception"+e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 * main
 *----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JMSExample5.sendTopicMessage(SERVICE_QUEUE,
            "<?xml version = \"1.0\" encoding = \"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
                    "<MYServices>\n" +
                    " <header>\n" +
                    "  <Version>1.0</Version>\n" +
                    "  <SrvType>OML</SrvType>\n" +
                    "  <SrvName>REQ_BALANCE_ENQUIRY</SrvName>\n" +
                    "  <SrcApp>BNK</SrcApp>\n" +
                    "  <OrgId>BLA</OrgId>\n" +
                    " </header>\n" +
                    " <body>\n" +
                    "  <srv_req>\n" +
                    "   <req_credit_card_balance_enquiry>\n" +
                    "    <card_no>12345678</card_no>\n" +
                    "   </req_credit_card_balance_enquiry>\n" +
                    "  </srv_req>\n" +
                    " </body>\n" +
                    "</MYServices>\n");
}
```

}